# nodeJS video streaming, connection not closing when user disconnects or moved to different page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, video, stream

I am building a video streaming server in nodeJS using express and using "request-progress" module to get the progress status.
It's(video streaming) working fine.

**But the problem is, even after I close the browser or moves to next page, the server still streaming data. I can see that in console.**

Here is the code for the same:

```
app.route('/media/*').get(function (req, res) {

  var originalUrl = "http://myactualserver.com";
  var resourceUrl = originalUrl.split('media');
  var requestURL = BASE_URL + resourceUrl[1];

  req.on('close', function () {
    console.log('Client closed the connection');
  });

  var options = {};
  progress(request(requestURL), {
    throttle: 1000,
    delay: 0,
    lengthHeader: 'content-length',
  })
    .on('progress', function (state) {
      console.log('progress', state);
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('err');
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('end');
    })
    .pipe(res);
});
```

I tried the following post and finally added the

```
req.on("close", function(){});
```

[Video Streaming with nodejs and Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388976/video-streaming-with-nodejs-and-express)

[node.js http server, detect when clients disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572572/node-js-http-server-detect-when-clients-disconnect)

[Node.js server keeps streaming data even after client disconnected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496634/node-js-server-keeps-streaming-data-even-after-client-disconnected)

**My question is:

1. How will call either the "error" or "end" function of "request-progress"? 

2. How will I close the streaming? 

3. Why `console.log('Client closed the connection');`
is called twice?**

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions:

1. You can probably use emit from events.EventEmitter

Refer this example

https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-request-progress/blob/master/test/test.js

Alternatively you can use the last progress status in close function.

2. Not sure what is the question here, the progress will continue till the socket is closed.
3. If you are making the request from browser (default player), it makes two requests.